# For Loop is executing only once in Protractor Tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, protractor, ui-automation

I am trying to automate angular application. I have dropdown of elements stored in an array. I want to loop through all the array elements and do some operation if the condition is satisfied. But the for loop is running only once.

```
expect(element(by.css('button.button.primary')).isPresent()).toBe(true).then(function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
        browser.sleep(2000);
        console.log(array1);
        console.log('Configuring ' + array1[0][i]);
        browser.sleep(3000);

        //  First sens config
        if (array1[0][i] === 'Sens1') {
            element(By.linkText(array1[0][i])).click().then(function() {
                console.log('Configuring ' + array1[0][i]);
            });

            element(by.xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')).click();
            browser.sleep(1000);
            browser.driver.findElement(by.css('button.button.primary')).click().then(function() {
                browser.sleep(1000);
            });
        });

}

// Second Sens Config
else if (array1[0][i] === ''
    Sens2 ')') {
    element(By.linkText(array1[0][i])).click().then(function() {
        console.log('Configuring ' + array1[0][i]);
    });
    element(by.xpath('//se-sensor-chooser-table//tr/td[4]')).getText().then(function(state) {

        element(by.xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')).click();
        browser.sleep(1000);
        browser.driver.findElement(by.css('button.button.primary')).click().then(function() {
            browser.sleep(1000);
        });
    });
} else {
    console.log('No Sensors');
}
```

}

Comment: Firstly, use `i++` instead of `++i`. Secondary, you have a mistake inside `else if` condition.

Comment: Verify the opening and closing of the `for` loop. `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntax errors in your code around `if..else`. Now, from your code, you have two dimension array. For your for loop to execute multiple times, your array should have more than one elements for first index. Meaning - if you have an array `array1 =[ ['Sens1','Sens2','Sens1','Sens2','Sens3']];` and you use `array1.length` inside your for loop, it will be executed only once and not five times as the length of the array is one. If you want to iterate over each element here, you will have to use `array1[0].length` in your for loop. I have added an array for your reference, formatted and corrected your code below. You can run it to see it's working and then un comment and it should work, unless there isn't anything logical missing from your end. Make sure you have proper array. Hope it helps.

Try -

```
//expect(element(by.css('button.button.primary')).isPresent()).toBe(true).then(function () {
    array1 =[ ['Sens1','Sens2','Sens1','Sens2','Sens3']];
    for (var i = 0; i < array1[0].length; i++) {
        console.log("inside forloop");
        /* browser.sleep(2000);
        console.log(array1);
        console.log('Configuring ' + array1[0][i]);
        browser.sleep(3000); */

        //  First sens config
        if (array1[0][i] === 'Sens1') {
            console.log("inside if");
            /* element(By.linkText(array1[0][i])).click().then(function () {
                console.log('Configuring ' + array1[0][i]);
            });

            element(by.xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')).click();
            browser.sleep(1000);
            browser.driver.findElement(by.css('button.button.primary')).click().then(function () {
                browser.sleep(1000);
            }); */
        } else if (array1[0][i] === 'Sens2') {
            console.log("inside else");
            /* element(By.linkText(array1[0][i])).click().then(function () {
                console.log('Configuring ' + array1[0][i]);
            });
            element(by.xpath('//se-sensor-chooser-table//tr/td[4]')).getText().then(function (state) {

                element(by.xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')).click();
                browser.sleep(1000);
                browser.driver.findElement(by.css('button.button.primary')).click().then(function () {
                    browser.sleep(1000);
                });
            }); */
        } else {
            console.log('No Sensors');
        }

    }
//});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I used map instead of for loop, so that it will iterate through all the elements and perform required actions.

Comment: @ThulasiRajuAD, Great.